# Paperclip file size validation error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, paperclip-validation

```
validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 5.megabytes
```

gives an error message of

```
Image file size must be less than 5242880 Bytes
```

This isn't very user friendly.. Is there a way to make the message to be

```
Image file size must be less than 5 MB
```

? without setting a custom message on my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can.

I just added a message.

```
validates_attachment_size :cover_image, :in => 0.megabytes..6.megabytes, :message => 'must be smaller than 6mb'
```

My error is now: 'Cover_image must be smaller than 6mb.'

(Would be nice if I could change 'Cover_image' so something more user-friendly. But still beats 'Cover_image file size must be less than 5242880 Bytes')

Comment: took a year, but an answer is and answer :)

Comment: To be fair, your question was "without setting a custom message on my own", and my answer does state "You need to set a custom message to get that format"...

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You need to set a custom message to get that format. You can see from the paperclip source that they convert the size to an integer number of bytes in [`human_size`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/validators/attachment_size_validator.rb#L66).

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the gem you use?
I had the same problem, updating it to 4.2 solved the problem (The function `human_size` is now using the `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_human_size` function in order to make it readable)